# Transparent Window with Border

Tags: wpf, transparent

I am trying to make a Window in WPF transparent, including the border (minimize-, maximize-buttons and so on). I want to make a window behave like the search window in Notepad++, when not in focus it should be transparent (see through), and when it is focused it should be non-transparent.
I don't want to set my WindowStyle to None since I want to preserve the WindowStyle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you pertaining to Custom Window Chrome? 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: I don't want custom Chrome. I want the whole Window to be "see-through", the Chrome and all of the Content.